# Search for Passive DNS Replication database

Tags: dns

I'm looking for a Passive DNS Replication database.
It exists in virustotal and securitytrails.
Is there a more comprehensive database of dns data by IP address?

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately questions of the type, "where can I find X?" are off-topic as the answers might change from day to day.

Comment: Also, I googled "Passive DNS Replication" and got a ton of resources. For instance, this list: https://securityintelligence.com/how-to-use-passive-dns-to-inform-your-incident-response/